# How to add contents using InnerHTML inside of an element i created using DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

1. Hello Guys so i made a DOM tag using Javascript and i gave it an ID as follows:

   ***let Tagger = document.createElement('h3');***

***Tagger.id = 'Game';***

2. After doing so i attempted to give Tagger content by doing as follows:

`document.getElementById(Tagger).innerHTML = "Hello World";`

3. When i console.log the page it gives me the following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null*

4. So instead of using the Tagger variable i tried using the id name and it worked. This is what i did:
    `document.getElementById("Game").innerHTML = "Hello World";`

5)The problem is that i dont want to use the id directly but i want to use the variable name called Tagger, what could be wrong with my first approach?

Comment: `document.getElementById` accepts a string. `Tagger` is an element. You can’t query the document for elements that you haven’t added yet, and for created elements, especially, this is pointless. Just do `Tagger.innerHTML = "Hello World"`. `document.getElementById(Tagger)` is the same as `document.getElementById(String(Tagger))`, which is `document.getElementById("[object HTMLHeadingElement]")`. Remember, `Tagger.id` is `"Game"`; `Tagger` is _not_ `"Game"`.

Comment: Also, you may not need the ID. For a title, it’s useful for fragment identifiers in URLs. But IDs are not needed to _create_ elements. More compact version of your code (plus best practices): `const tagger = Object.assign(document.createElement("h3"), { innerHTML: "Hello World" })`.

Answer (score 2):

`Tagger` is a reference to the created element object, not its id.

Just set the content the same way you set the ID

```js
let Tagger = document.createElement('h3');

Tagger.id = 'Game';

Tagger.innerHTML = 'Hello World';

document.body.append(Tagger)
```

Comment: now i want to add CSS to that H3 element using its variable name called Tagger, how would i do this? I tried:   document.getElementById(Tagger).style.color = "blue"; it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Tagger = document.createElement('h1');
Tagger.id = 'h1Title';
Tagger.innerHTML = 'Hello World';

// First you need Insert in the document to found in document
document.body.append(Tagger)

//After inserted in the document, is possible to found
let h1 = document.getElementById("h1Title");
h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World 2 - The Revenge';
```

Comment: If you already have a reference to the element why would you need to query for it in the DOM with `getElementById()`

Comment: I created it just to explain how it works, nothing else. it doesn't really make sense, but it serves as an explanation.